# Construction of a recurrence sequence with given period

Tags: recurrence-relations, finite-fields, cryptography, coding-theory

I want to construct a binary recurrence sequence which has period 1023. Moreover, it shouldn't have pre-period.
Can anyone help me with the procedure? I truly have no ideas where to start.
Also, I don't expect a full solution, but at least some help would be very much appreciated.

Thank you in advance

Comment: Why not take the sequence $1,2,3,\ldots,1023$ and then repeat it over?

Comment: It should be binary, so it can only take values 0 and 1

Comment: you can write the same numbers in binary, that won't really change the nature of the thing

Comment: I mean, we are working on a finite field of two elements, so 3 would be 1, 4 would be 0 and so on, and the sequence you gave me would be (0,1,0,1,0,1,....) which has obviously no period equal to 1023...

Comment: ok how about $0,1,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,\ldots$

Comment: how about the sequence $ x \mapsto x\cdot 10 \bmod 14323 $ ? And to get a binary output for each $x$ you can do $x \bmod 2$ afterwards. It has a cycle length of 1023. Depending on chosen starting value $x_0$ you will get 1 out of 14 different sequences.

Comment: As written, any binary sequence with $a_{k+1023}=a_k$ (and $a_0,\dots,a_{1022}$ arbitrary) satisfies the conditions.

Comment: **HINT:** $1023=2^{10}-1$. Do you know what a Linear Feedback Shift Register is?

Comment: @K.defaoite Now that you mentioned it, yes we just introduced LFSR. I still have to understand it well, but if I got it right, by your hint I should construct a maximal LFSR of length 10, choose appropriate taps and then get a satisfying sequence? I am sorry if I am saying something completely wrong

Comment: @Miresh Yes. Construct a maximal LFSR of order 10. This involves finding a $10\times 10$ matrix of $1$s and zeros such that its characteristic polynomial $c(x)$ divides $x^{2^{10}-1}-1$ but does not divide $x^{2^k-1}-1$ for any $k<10$.
Probably you will need some sort of computer program.

Comment: I think should end up with $a_n=a_{n-10}+a_{n-7}+1$. As for the initial condition $a_0\dots a_9$, I must admit I'm not sure.

Comment: @K.defaoite thank you very much for your help, your comment is very useful. Now I will try to figure out everything that's left

Comment: Indeed, $x^{10}+x^3+1$ and its reciprocal $x^{10}+x^7+1$ are both primitive polynomials. You can use either as the feedback polynomial in an LFSR. There are also other alternatives.

Answer (score 1):

To give a unified answer, if you want a linear recurrence of period $2^n-1$ you need to use a recurrence whose characteristic polynomial $c(x)$ is primitive, i.e., $n$ is the smallest value of $k$ for which $c(x)$ divides $x^{2^k-1}-1$ as polynomials in $\mathbb{F}_2[x].$ There are tables of these polynomials you can refer to, for example see [here](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary?doi=10.1.1.98.2591).

And since you did not specify that the recurrence had to be *linear* note that there are nonlinear recurrences which can also give periodic sequences (as pointed out by @JyrkiLahtonen). Just as an example the nonlinear recurrence
$$
s(t+3)=s(t)+s(t+1)+s(t+1)s(t+2)\pmod 2
$$
with the initial condition $(s(0),s(1),s(2))=(0,0,1)$ generates the sequence below which has period 4:
$$
00110011\cdots
$$